# How to fix timeout: the monitored command dumped core, in C?

Tags: c

I'm doing some homework, however, in the act of compiling the program, the compiler is aborting an error. This only happens in the compiler of a specific website where I have to upload the code.

I'm new to C so there's probably something I did wrong. I hope someone experienced in the language can find where this problem is, because I have no idea, only in the [beecrowd](https://www.beecrowd.com.br/) compiler that doesn't compile, and that's exactly where I should upload it.

**Source code**

```
#include <stdio.h>


int obterNumeroFaltante(int matriz[], int n)
{
    int i;
    int resultado;
    
    resultado = (n + 1) * (n + 2) / 2;
    
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        resultado = resultado - matriz[i];
    }
    
    return resultado;
}
 

int main()
{
    int n1, n2;
    int i;
    int resultado;
    
    scanf("%d", &n1);
    
    n2 = n1 - 1;
    
    int matriz[sizeof n2];
    
    for (i = 0; i < n2; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &matriz[i]);
    }
    
    resultado = obterNumeroFaltante(matriz, n2);
    
    printf("%d\n", resultado);
}
```

**Error**

```
timeout: the monitored command dumped core
```

Comment: `-fsanitize=address` is great for debugging all kinds of memory issues. Hint: What do you think `sizeof n2` is?

Comment: `sizeof n2` is probably 2 or 4, the size of `n2` in bytes. That relates to the _maximum_  value it can hold (e.g. 32767), not the actual value.

Comment: `int matriz[sizeof n2]` -> `int matriz[n2];`. `sizeof n2` is the size of the `n2` variable itself, the same as `sizeof(int)` which is usually 2, 4, or 8 depending on your platform.

Answer (score 2):

This line is where the error is

```
int matriz[sizeof n2];
```

`sizeof n2` will give you the size of 'int' in bytes (usually 4). This will make an array of 4 elements. Accessing anything outside this array will be a memory access violation.

Based on your code the line should be replaced by

```
int matriz[n2];
```

Note that this will create an array of `n2` elements.